# Call method from one class when calling methods from another

Tags: javascript, class

I have two classes: first on checks that file exists and it's valid; second one make some stuff with that file:

```
class Validator {
   constructor(){
      this.file = './file.json';
   }
   check(){ ... }
}

class Modificator {
   action1(){ ... }
   action2(){ ... }
}
```

What I want is the method from first class automatically calls inside each method from the second class.
It's a bit tricky stuff, but I'm really don't want to do it manually, like so:

```
class Validator {
   constructor(){
      this.file = './file.json';
   }
   static check(){ ... }
}

class Modificator {
   action1(){ 
      let status = Validator.check();
      ...
   }
   action2(){ 
      let status = Validator.check();
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the relationship between Validator and Modificator? Why do all Modificators need to call the same static method from Validator?

Answer (score 0):

1. By using a wrapper

```js
class Validator {
  static check () {console.log('checked')}
  static checkCbk (fn) {
    return _ => {
      this.check()
      //then callback
      fn()
    }
  }
}
class Modificator {
  //via public instance field
  action1 = Validator.checkCbk(function () {
    console.log('mod::action1')
  })
}
//or by prototype
Modificator.prototype.action2 = Validator.checkCbk(function(){
  console.log('mod::action2')
})
var m = new Modificator()
m.action1()
m.action2()
```

However notice that if you were to subclass `Modificator`, you could forget to rewrap your methods...

2. By making a contract

More commonly by making a contract and delegating to implem if contract is fulfilled.

This way you don't have to worry when extending since check is made in base class anyway.

```js
class Validator {
  static check () {console.log('checked')}
}
class Contract {
  action1 () {
    Validator.check()
    this._action1()
  }
}
class M2 extends Contract {
  _action1 () {
    console.log('mod2::action1')
  }
}
var m = new M2()
m.action1()
```